# How to add page breaks every 30 rows

Tags: excel, vba

This is what I have:

```
 Sub Page_Break()
     For i = 1 To 799 Step 30
         ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=Cells(i + 1, 1)
     Next
 End Sub
```

- I need the first page to be rows 1-30 the second to be 31-60, etc.
- Right now its not being consistent with the # of rows/ Page.
- I've made sure row height is the same for all rows.

Comment: Your code breaks the pages like this: Page1: 1-1, Page2: 2 to 31, Page3: 32 to 61, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the For like this:

```
For i = 30 To 799 Step 30
```

The rest of the code is fine, unless you have merged cells and other complicating stuff.